# UIPickerView as inputView gets messed up on orientation change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation, uipickerview, inputview

I'm using a standard UIPicker view as an inputView for a textField in an iPhone application. When the view is loaded in either landscape or portrait, the picker is sized the same as the appropriate keyboard. However, when you rotate the device once inside the view the picker doesn't resize it's height properly, like it does with it's width. I have UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth set. When I tried setting UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight as well the picker gets messed up (choppy graphics, component cuts off) on rotation, though the height is correct! Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 3):

I found that if you are working with iOS 7 simply add:

```
pickerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

This solved the problem for me. The transition isn't very choppy, looks like it "should" look.

Answer (score 0):

I found a band-aid:

In `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` in your hosting viewController, call `setNeedsLayout` on that picker view. The weird layout glitches are visible during the rotate but clean up at the end.

Comment: That pickerView is the inputView of the textField. So it can't be accessed in parent ViewController